# Why does Kafka Streams app fail with AccessDeniedException on Windows for state cleanup?

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Kafka Streams 2.1.0 on MS Windows here.

I'm on macOS so can't work on it myself, but while working with people who were on MS Windows they reported `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` when they used [KafkaStreams.cleanUp](http://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/streams/KafkaStreams.html) in a Kafka Streams application every time they started the app (except the first time).

In [Deleting topics throws exception #196](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/issues/196) it was asked why a Kafka Streams application would fail with `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` when running `EmbeddedSingleNodeKafkaCluster#deleteTopicsAndWait`.

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\gwade\AppData\Local\Temp\junit6747789160683566966\junit5490786451417386230\topic-0 -> C:\Users\gwade\AppData\Local\Temp\junit6747789160683566966\junit5490786451417386230\topic-0.a3c80cfca5e740bd8c1be434d817af2c-delete
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileCopy.move(WindowsFileCopy.java:387)
        at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.move(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:287)
        at java.nio.file.Files.move(Files.java:1395)
        at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.atomicMoveWithFallback(Utils.java:809)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$renameDir$1.apply$mcV$sp(Log.scala:728)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$renameDir$1.apply(Log.scala:726)
        at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$renameDir$1.apply(Log.scala:726)
        at kafka.log.Log.maybeHandleIOException(Log.scala:1927)
        at kafka.log.Log.renameDir(Log.scala:726)
        at kafka.log.LogManager.asyncDelete(LogManager.scala:842)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition$$anonfun$delete$1.apply(Partition.scala:353)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inLock(CoreUtils.scala:251)
        at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$.inWriteLock(CoreUtils.scala:259)
        at kafka.cluster.Partition.delete(Partition.scala:347)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplica(ReplicaManager.scala:350)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$stopReplicas$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:380)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager$$anonfun$stopReplicas$2.apply(ReplicaManager.scala:378)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
        at kafka.server.ReplicaManager.stopReplicas(ReplicaManager.scala:378)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handleStopReplicaRequest(KafkaApis.scala:200)
        at kafka.server.KafkaApis.handle(KafkaApis.scala:111)
        at kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandler.run(KafkaRequestHandler.scala:69)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea what the root cause is?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround was to shut down Zookeeper and remove the `/tmp/zookeeper` (which simply removed the entire state of a Kafka cluster, incl. topics to be deleted with their local directories on brokers).